# PHP delete/update only affects last MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Whether using the delete or update function, only the last row is updated/deleted. It doesn't matter what field I update/delete, only the last row is passed. I'm unable to find the issue other than the fact that a unique ID is not being passed. I'm new to PDO, so I'm not too familiar with debugging. Any help is appreciated.
[image: Example of output]

```
<form action="" id="form" method="post">
<?php
function UserForm($customers = array())
    { 
        ob_start(); ?>
        <?php
            $id = $customers['id']; 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $customers['name']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $customers['email']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $customers['phone']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="<?php echo $customers['address']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="proudct" name="product" value="<?php echo $customers['product']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="firmware" name="firmware" value="<?php echo $customers['firmware']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker" name="purchase_date" value="<?php echo $customers['purchase_date']; ?>"></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="delete" value="X" onclick="return confirm('WARNING! \n\nAre you sure you want to DELETE?')" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_update" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update <?php echo $id; ?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        $data   =   ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $data;
    } ?>



<?php
$pdo    =   new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
//$query  =   $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY purchase_date ASC");
if (isset($_POST['desc'])){
$sort = "desc";
$query  =   $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY purchase_date DESC");
}
else {
$sort = "asc";
$query  =   $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY purchase_date ASC");
} 
$query->execute(); 
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Firmware Version</th>
        <th align="center">
        Purchase Date
        <?php 
        if ($sort == "asc") {
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="Desc" name="desc" id="sort">'; 
        echo '<a name="desc" href="javascript: submitform()">Desc</a>';
        }
        else {
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="Asc" name="asc" id="sort">'; 
        echo '<a name="asc" href="javascript: submitform()">Asc</a>';
        }
        ?>
        </th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<?php
while($customers = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo UserForm($customers);
} //end of while

// Delete customer
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
try{
        $id     =   $_POST['id'];
        $query  =   $pdo->prepare("delete from customers where id = :id");
        $query->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        echo "Customer successfully deleted." . $_POST['id'];
        echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=view_edit.php">';
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Failed to delete the MySQL database table ... :".$e->getMessage();
    } //end of try
} //end of isset delete

// Edit customer
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
try {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $id = $_POST['id']; 
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone =  $_POST['phone'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $product = $_POST['product'];
        $firmware = $_POST['firmware'];
        $purchase_date = $_POST['purchase_date'];  
        $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE customers SET name = '$name', email = '$email', phone = '$phone', address = '$address', product = '$product', firmware = '$firmware', purchase_date = '$purchase_date' where id = '$id'");
        $query -> execute( array(
        ':name' => $name,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':phone' => $phone,
        ':address' => $address,
        ':product' => $product,
        ':firmware' => $firmware,
        ':purchase_date' => $purchase_date
        ));
        echo "Customer succesfully updated" . $id;
        echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=view_edit.php">';
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error! Failed to update customers :".$e->getMessage();
}//end of try
} //end of isset update

?>
```

Comment: I would expect a question tagged "mysql" to have some SQL code in it.

Comment: Used the suggested tags from stackoverflow. See above.

Comment: also, why are you using `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You should also pay attention to the other tags: PHP/MySQL.

Comment: `where id = '$id'");` you're not binding the id here, as per `$query ->bindParam(':id', htmlspecialchars($id));` and again `htmlspecialchars()` does nothing for prepared statements/SQL injection, it could even cause more trouble if anything.

Comment: Fred, htmlspecialchars() isn't effective against XSS? Removed the bindParam.

Comment: @eod not in prepared statements and as I said, it could be doing more harm than good, stripping away possibly good/valid characters. XSS is for displaying, not for queries. Prepared statements takes care of that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, got it. Removing hmlspecialchars and will update code.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` for your inputs, that's perfect and is fine for all of those, so you can keep those, but don't use them for your prepared statements. As for `where id = '$id'");` that should read as `where id = :id");` to go with the `$query ->bindParam(':id',` in the UPDATE.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, when I replaced '$id' with :id I get:

Error! Failed to update customers :SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Now you have `if ($sort == "asc")` and using `value="Asc"` those are case-sensitive, same for `value="Desc"`. I also don't see a POST array for both `name="desc"` and `name="asc"`. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: The desc/asc post works fine. Enabled error reporting, no output.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The issue was with the <form> tag not being printed above each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug your code, try using `print_r($_POST); exit();` immediately after your `if(isset($_POST['delete/update'])) {` to see what's being passed in the array when you post.

I'm a bit of a noob myself, but I suspect the problem here could be you haven't defined where your form starts and ends, so you're submitting the whole table. Try adding a form for each of your records, with a form name the same as your customer id. 
`<form name="formname<?php echo $id; ?>">` ... your input fields and submit button... `</form>`, then when you submit, you'll only be submitting that particular form and the data it contains.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

$query  =   $pdo->prepare("delete from customers where id = :id"

I bet this ID is unique..

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. Moved the `<form>` tag above the beginning of the table row.